# How to make filter/search bar search only when 3 characters has been entered?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have here a search bar from w3schools website which I have tweaked.

Right now, it will show all results at the first letter entered which is slowing down my site since there's more than 5000+ results in one go.

I wonder how can I make this search ONLY after 3 (or 4-5) characters/letters have been inputted?

Here's the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1u7mdLxf/)

**Here's the script so far:**

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          var $input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
              $table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
              $$tr   = $table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"),
              $noResults = $table.querySelector("tfoot tr");
              
          for (var i = 0; i < $$tr.length; i++) {
            var $$td    = $$tr[i].querySelectorAll("td"),
                  name    = $$td[0].innerText,
                country = $$td[1].innerText;
            $$tr[i].normalizedValue = normalizeStr( name + " " + country );
          }
          $input.addEventListener("input", performSearch);

          function performSearch() {
            var filter = normalizeStr(this.value),
                    resultCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $$tr.length; i++) {

              var isMatch = filter.length > 0 && $$tr[i].normalizedValue.includes(filter);
              if (isMatch) { resultCount++; }

              $$tr[i].classList[isMatch ? "add" : "remove"]("visible");
            }

            var showNoResultsMessage = resultCount === 0 && filter.length > 0;
            $noResults.classList[showNoResultsMessage ? "add" : "remove"]("visible");
          }

          function normalizeStr(str) {
            return (str || '').toUpperCase().trim();
          }
        });
    </script>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
#myInput{
    font-size:15px;
    width:90%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    outline: none;
    color: #000000;
}
input::placeholder {
    color: #000000;
}
#myTable{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:90%;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
#myTable td, #myTable th{
    text-align:left;
    padding:8px;
}
#myTable td a
}
#myTable tr{
    border-bottom:1px solid #222222;
}
#myTable thead tr, /* notice the use of thead */
#myTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #e0f2f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#myTable tbody tr {
    display: none; /* Hide rows by default */
}

#myTable tbody tr.visible {
    display: table-row; /* Show them when they match */
}

#myTable tfoot tr:not(.visible) {
    display: none; /* Hide the "no results" message if not visible */
}

#myTable tfoot td {
    text-align: center;
}
input:focus,
    select:focus,
    textarea:focus,
    button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

**and the HTML:**

```
<input class="mt-4 mx-auto" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search"/>

<table class="mb-5" id="myTable" align="center"><tbody>

<tr><td><a href="https://quip.com/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Quip</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Facebook</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Instagram</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Twitter</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://web.telegram.org/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Telegram</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://open.spotify.com/" target="_blank"><b>BM: </b>Spotify</a></td><td><p hidden></p></td></tr>

</table>
```

I would really appreciate all the help. Cheers! :)

Comment: Apart from just checking length you might want to research how to *"throttle" or  "debounce"* to prevent search on every keystroke allowing user a bit of time to type each character

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Will definitely look that up soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', performSearch);

    function performSearch() {
        if (this.value.length < 3) return;
        // search code
    }
});
```

If you have any questions, ask.

Comment: Hi, can you please teach me how to embed the code you gave above on my script?

I tried it and it won't work on mine (cause I'm not really good at JS)

Comment: @TheAuthor Put this code: `if (this.value.length < 3) return;` as the 1st line of your `performSearch` function like I did. It's checking whether or not input value length is less than 3 characters. If it is then it exits the function. And of course, you can change 3 to any number you want.

Comment: It finally worked! Although now, when I delete the input, the results would stay in sight, instead of being hidden again. Can you please help with this?

Comment: @TheAuthor As I understand the last two lines of your `performSearch` function are responsible for showing and hiding search results and as we are exiting the function when the input value is too small these lines are not performed so results aren't hidden. So I think you should change this line: `if (this.value.length < 3) return;` to this: `if (this.value.length < 3) {
    // hide all results
    return;
}` so when the input is smaller than a specific value (3), results are deleted. P.S. this kind of behaviour may not be very suitable for you.

Comment: It won't work now :( To make my request clear, the script you first gave me works the way I need it. But let me explain the problem I'm experiencing in a little scenario: If i type "face" it will show the result with "face" like "facebook", but if I change my mind and just deleted the input "face" that I typed, the results is still showing on my screen instead of being hidden again. Btw, if you're busy I'd understand it and it's perfectly fine. Really appreciate all your help!

Comment: @TheAuthor Sorry, I didn't read your code well and I misunderstood it, your request was clear.
Try this:
`if (this.value.length < 3) {
     for (var i = 0; i < $$tr.length; i++) {
         $$tr[i].classList["remove"]("visible");
    }
    return;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218592/discussion-between-michael-chon-and-the-author).

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Chon! It's perfect now! Hooray!